# php e query with if else

Tags: php, mysql

every day I get a xml file from which to extrapolate ( with php) a set of data ( about a thousand records) and memorize them in mysql ( so everything is ok) .

For simplicity we assume that the XML file contains the following fields:

```
date (AAAAMMDD) ;
replace ('S','N');
progressive (1,2,... n);
field 1 ;
field 2 ;
....
field n;
```

and that the mysql table is as follows:

```
id;
date;
substitution;
progressive ;
field1 ;
field2 ;
....
fieldn;
```

In the xml file if I have the replacement field = 'S' means that the file replaces a file sent previously and the progressive indicates the version (might get more substitutions).

Now I would like to handle this in this way :

```
1. if data != '$date' then insert in MySQL
2. if data = '$data' and replace = 'S' and progressive > $progressive then update
3. if data = '$data' and replace = 'S' and progressive <= $progressive then go out
```

For point 1 all ok, but I can not handle 2 and 3. 
Could you help me ?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there should only exists one entry for a given date in your db it should be:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM [tablename] WHERE date = :date");
$stmt->bindValue(':date',$date);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetch();

if($res['cnt'] > 0) {
    if($replace == 'S') {

        $query = 'UPDATE [tablename] SET [fields_to_update] WHERE date = :date AND progressive > :progressive';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':date',$date);
        $stmt->bindValue(':progressive',$progressive, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

    } else {
        // do nothing because you have an entry that should not be updated
    }
} else {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO [tablename] ...';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Steven, In my case, then I should do: if($replace == 'S') { $query = 'UPDATE [tablename] SET [fields_to_update] WHERE date = '$date' AND progressive > $progressive'; else $query = 'insert ....'; } correct?

Comment: not really. When `($replace != 'S')` it is not always an `insert`. It is an insert if the data doesnt exists in db, isn't it? Please also be carefull with `WHERE date = '$date' AND progressive > $progressive'` because date is not your primary key i think. Use your primary key for `where` when you have more than one entry with the same date.